# Loading model to HTML DropDownListFor helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have a simple Model called `Region` which is like

```
namespace App
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Region
    {
        public int RegionID { get; set; }
        public string RegionDescription { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and I am trying to load the model into a HTML `DropDownListFor()`  helper in view like

```
@model IEnumerable<App.Region>

<div class="row">
    @Html.DropDownListFor("RegionList",
                    new SelectList(model => model.RegionDescription),
                    "Select Region",
                    new { @class = "form-control" })

</div>
```

or

```
@model IEnumerable<App.Region>
<div class="row">
    @Html.DropDownListFor("RegionList",
                        new SelectList(s => s.RegionDescription),
                        "Select Region",
                        new { @class = "form-control" })

</div>
```

or:

```
@model IEnumerable<App.Region>
<div class="row">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor("RegionList",
                        new SelectList(model => item.RegionDescription),
                        "Select Region",
                        new { @class = "form-control" })
}
</div>
```

but in both ways I am getting this error.

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a
>   delegate type

Why is this happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: `SelectList` constructor does takes a collection. not a lamda expression. Where did you get that information from ?

Comment: Hi Thanks for comment Shyju, I was following this `Link`(http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-dropdownlist-dropdownlistfor)

Comment: The link you provided does not have any code like what you have in your question!

Comment: how about this part `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StudentGender, `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SelectList` constructor takes a collection as the first argument. not a lamda expression ! You are using the helper method in an incorrect way!

Ideally, `Html.DropDownListFor` method's first parameter is an expression from which the helper will be able to get the value of the view model property. That means, to use it, your view model should have a property to store the selected option value. So create a view model like this

```
public class CreateVm
{
  public int SelectedRegion { set;get;}
  public List<SelectListItem> Regions { set;get;}
}
```

Now in your GET action, you need to create an object of this view model, load the Regions collection property and send that to the view

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var vm = new CreateVm();
  vm.Regions = new List<SelectListItem>{
         new SelectListItem { Value="1", Text="Region1"},
         new SelectListItem { Value="2", Text="Region2"},
         new SelectListItem { Value="3", Text="Region3"}
  };
  return View(vm);
}
```

and in your view which is strongly typed to this new view model, you can use the `DropDownListFor` helper method like this

```
@model CreateVm
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.SelectedRegion,Model.Regions,"Select Region",
                                                            new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**Or** if you do want to use your existing view model/type passed to the view, you may consider using the `Html.DropDownList` helper method to render a SELECT element

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedRegion", 
                    new SelectList(Model, "RegionID", "RegionDescription"), "Select Region",
                    new { @class = "form-control" })
```

This will render a SELECT element with the name `"SelectedRegion"`

Comment: Thanks Shyju , the very last part of you code is doing what I was looking for but I can not understand why are you passing 3 parameters `Model, "RegionID", "RegionDescription"` in `SelectList`?

Comment: Model here is a list of your custom class `Region`. You need to tell SelectList to use the "RegionId" property value for the option value and "RegionDescription" property value for the option text